# Threejs deform mesh from heightmap

Tags: three.js, mesh, heightmap

How can I go about deforming an already created mesh with a heightmap in three.js? I did a few searches and couldn't find anything, so I'm asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are lucky, `three.js-r72` introduced vertex displacement in the `MeshPhongMaterial`. You set the displacement map like a `normalMap`:

```
var displacementMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/ninja/displacement.jpg" );

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                color: 0x0a0100,
                //...
                displacementMap: displacementMap,
                displacementScale: 2.436143,
                displacementBias: - 0.428408,
            } );
```

`scale`: The amount of displacement, "how tall are your spikes"

`bias`: Shift the center up or down

Official Example: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_displacementmap

Comment: Oh sweet! I didn't see that example before :)